# Backbone - What is the best location to insert JavaScript to manipulate the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I would like to have JavaScript tightly integrated with my Backbone templates, and as the views reference which template to use, I believe this would be the best location to store the JavaScript, right? But how?

In particular, I have JavaScript which sets up the DOM when the view has rendered and ready (not an event). I originally set this script in the template but this was only triggered when the application was first loaded, when you navigate back to the view through Backbone's routers, the JavaScript wasn't triggered.

Comment: Best bet is to post some code so we can see exactly what is going wrong or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you doing a Backbone.history.start() when you render your Backbone views? Seems like a router issue but you might be asking the wrong question also which makes it sound a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are not meant to store your JavaScript - they are supposed to be dumb html templates to be rendered by your views.

When you load a template from a View, this view needs to bind with all DOM Elements that will interact with your application.

It is good practice if your view has only bindings to the DOM then, so it can trigger internal events.

Then you can create "controllers" that will listen to your view instance and interact with it, triggering methods to do some change in the DOM, or preparing collections and models to be used by your view.

However, you can use lots of other libraries to organize your code logic loading.

I like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), but [commonjs](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules) has a lot of useful options.

Putting the JavaScript inside a template is like putting it mixed with your HTML. It's not a good idea, because you are mixing logic with structure and your application will get hard to maintain once it grows.

I organize my code with MVC style, which makes it is simple to grow and test large applications. For example, if I want models/collections, they are in the MODEL/COLLECTION folders, the CONTROLLER folder will keep the logical parts of my application, the VIEW folder will keep the files that interact with the DOM and like Django I added a Template folder for the templates, which are as simple as possible.

Just to explain your problem:

When you load a template with a script, you will execute the script. After this, your template will be stored in the memory, it means that your script inside will never be triggered again. You can fix it, but you will do it wrongly. Your script can be triggered after the render by binding your view render method in Backbone.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I knew it was a dirty solution. My question in short was: how do I execute JavaScript to manipulate the DOM on a view's domready? Been a little difficult finding an answer about this through Google.

Comment: @DallasClark did you look at Backbone examples page? If you are using jQuery, you can `$(function() { /* code here, dom is ready */});`, you also cam trigger scripts after executing views render, so if your view is already in the DOM, it will simple change the DOM, if not, you can render and append to an DOM element. Take a time with this site: http://backbonetutorials.com/ will help you.

Comment: Yes I have. I'm starting to understand it more now, it's just takes a little to get my head around Rails, Coffeescript, SASS, and Backbone all at once. 1 week in, I think I'm doing alright, thanks to people like yourself. Cheers !